# issues while using parfor in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

How is it possible to resolve this error. As this video upload takes too much time. Firstly I am reading a cell. Then creating histogram of a frame extracted from video, then comparing it with any previous frame and uploading only if there is any significant difference between histograms.

```
global currRowIndex;
global histCell;

if (fname ~= 0)

file_fullpath = strcat(pthname, fname);
[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(file_fullpath);
 mov=VideoReader(file_fullpath);
 data = read(mov, Inf);
 nFrames=mov.NumberOfFrames;

parfor k = 1: nFrames       
     waitbar(k/nFrames);

    if(k==1)
        index=currRowIndex;
        cell=histCell;
        currentFrame = read(mov, k);
        imgHSV=rgb2hsv(currentFrame);
        H = imgHSV(:,:,1);
        S = imgHSV(:,:,2);
        V = imgHSV(:,:,3);
        hHist = hist(H(:),16);
        sHist = hist(S(:),16);
        vHist = hist(V(:),16);
        index=index+1;
        cell(index,:,:,:,index)={name;hHist;sHist;vHist;categorySelected};
    else
        currentFrame = read(mov, k);
        imgHSV=rgb2hsv(currentFrame);
        H = imgHSV(:,:,1);
        S = imgHSV(:,:,2);
        V = imgHSV(:,:,3);
        hHist = hist(H(:),16);
        sHist = hist(S(:),16);
        vHist = hist(V(:),16);
        [rowCurr,colCurr,depthCurr]=size(cell);
         found=0;
         if(row==0)
             row=1;
         end                 
         for x=row:rowCurr

          dbRow=cell(x,:,:,:,x);
           H_Temp= getDiff(dbRow{2},hHist);
          if(H_Temp>2000  && dbRow{5}==categorySelected)
              found=1;  
              break;
           end
         end
        if(found==1)
        index=index+1;
        cell(index,:,:,:,index)={name;hHist;sHist;vHist;categorySelected};
        end

    end
 end
```

The error I get is as below

**??? Reference to a cleared variable cell.**

```
Error in ==> FrmUploadVideo>(parfor body) at 133
            [rowCurr,colCurr,depthCurr]=size(cell);
```

Comment: Does the code work using plain `for` instead of `parfor`?

Comment: your variable `cell` is only defined for the first iteration (`if (k==1)` block), with the statement `cell=histCell;`. But in a `parfor` loop, each iteration is supposed to be independant of the other one, so all the other iterations do not know the variable `cell` (undefined). You have to at least initialise the variable outside of the loop or at the beginning in a section common to all the iterations. Side note: you should change the name of this variable, as `cell` is the name of a Matlab built-in function. This might also create problems down the line...

Comment: Actually i tried with directly using histCell and currRowIndex. but i cannot use it directly as these are are not allowed. So had to change the code as above. If you can help me out with the global variables directly in parfor that will be great